# GCC puts constant pointers and constant integers into different memory regions

Tags: c, linker, embedded

I am working on an embedded C project using GCC for ARM V4.8.3. What I am trying to achieve is to place a structure into the FLASH (ROM) memory of the MCU. Since my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321095/what-is-the-most-general-approach-to-place-a-structure-into-the-flash-microcont/37321555?noredirect=1#comment62165428_37321555) I was thinking that each object identifier qualified as a constant (`const`) is to be placed into the `.rodata` section, which in my case (according to the liker script) is nested by `.text` which in other hand resides within the FLASH memory region.

I tend to think so because I checked one of my object definitions, which was a  constant pointer:

```
const char * const project_stringInvalidCharacter = "Invalid Character! \n";
```

The pointer was situated within FLASH if qualified as a constant.

But, when I defined a constant object of type int (`const uint_8 myObj;`), I saw that its address represented a number that belong to the RAM or `.bss`  region.

In other words `const` works for the pointer, but didn't for integer type. By works I mean it does what I expect, reasoning from my previous post, namely to "place" the identifier into the FLASH (ROM).

Comment: I swear no reported warnings at all.

Comment: @Olaf I am using eclipse IDE. Preferences->C/C++->Code Analysis        only two warning boxes are currently unchecked `Format String Vulnerabilities` and `Return with parenthesis`. I don't see warning that has something to do with unassigned read-only data objects. Or something like that. If you are familiar with Eclipse IDE  3.8.1, could you please help me to enable them?

Comment: Hmm.. I just checked and you really are right (how embarassing;-) for a global variable. Sorry, I just remembered I got this message once (long time ago), but this is only for non-static variables, as they are not guaranteed to be initialised. Makes sense - somehow. That's why askers are required to provide a [mcve]. (Yet, an automatic local would likely not be placed into `rodata` anyway). Only solution is to always initialise static `const` variables.

Comment: I had to dummy-edit to remove the DV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the compiler is a bit confused as you don't assign a value to your constant.
Try:

```
const uint_8 myValue=42;
```

and see where it will be located.

Comment: This is the moment where I hit my head into the wall.